# How to send json and images as django response?

Tags: python, django, image

Currently, I send JSON data using Django rest API, and now I have to add images to this data (60 images per request along with the other data). I thought about using sendfile to achieve that but I'm not quite sure that this is a possibility at all.

I've looked for other options but found nothing.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_data(request):
collage_list = []
try:
    for i in range(30):
        collage_list.append({"focal_brand":{"collage_id": 7,"brand_name":"name"})
except Exception as e:
   print(e)
   return JsonResponseNotFound()
return JsonResponse(status=200, data=dict(respone=collage_list)
```

Can I send both (the JSON data and the files) together? How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to send the URLs of the images along with some metadata for each (as needed) e.g.:

```
images = [
    {
        'source': 'https://example.com/image/1.png',
        'brand_name': 'some brand',
        'foo': 'bar',
    },
    ...
    ...
]

return JsonResponse(status=200, data=dict(images=images))
```

This way your response would not become bulky due to the transfer of large chunk of binary data. And the client can retrieve the images from the URLs as required.

Comment: True, but it would either require another server for this to work, or multiple requests. Posting to another server might be an area of concern when the image is containing personal information as face, identification details, etc.. Setting up an image server might be useful, although an overkill if the application doesn't deal with many images.